# stm32 rtc how to set timer alarm not time and date alarm

Tags: stm32, real-time-clock

I'm using Stm32f101vbt6 i want to set rtc alarm every 25 second.because i want to wake up microcontroller from stop mode to reset the watchdog.
in HAL libraries i can set rtc alarm by this command:

HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &RTC_Alarm_Time, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);

but for this command i have to get time from rtc which is hour min and sec and calculate 25 second after and then write the command above.
what should i do if i don't want to calculate time each time and set rtc alarm just by adding numbers to RTC alarm register.

Thank you.